until the window handle has been created Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control
This is the exception i am getting while updating my UI in a non UI thread. Like I have few labels on a winform, and i want to update the data of labels from a thread. When i try to update i got this error.
I tried this code in my thread to update labels. Some time it does not throw exception and some time it give exception.
Kindly provide any solution to this problem.
try
{
    int noOfFiles = Convert.ToInt16(aunApduPayloadBuff[0]);

    objDeviceStatusForm.lblNumberOfFiles.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        objDeviceStatusForm.lblNumberOfFiles.Text = noOfFiles.ToString();

        if (noOfFiles % 20 == 0)
        {
            objDeviceStatusForm.lblTotalPages.Text = Convert.ToString(noOfFiles / 20);
        }
        else
        {
            objDeviceStatusForm.lblTotalPages.Text = Convert.ToString((noOfFiles / 20) + 1);
        }
        objDeviceStatusForm.lblPageInfo.Text = $"Page {currentPage} of {objDeviceStatusForm.lblTotalPages.Text}";
        //objDeviceStatusForm.totalPages = noOfFiles/20;
        decimal percentage = ((decimal)noOfFiles / (decimal)SER_CONSTANTS.FDR_FILES_LIMIT_IN_DRIVE) * 100;
        decimal drivetotalPercentageRounded = Math.Round(percentage, 2); // rounded to 2 decimal places.
        objDeviceStatusForm.lblUsedDrivePercentage.Text = $"{drivetotalPercentageRounded} %";
    });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ExceptionsLogger.WriteErrorLog($"An Error occured during UpdateTotalEDRFilesAndDriveUsedLabelUsingPage1Information :{ex.Message}");
}


Your title (with the presumed exception message) is very clear what the problem is. You can use Invoke or BeginInvoke only after the control completed the creation phase (only then the window handle is valid).

Is objDeviceStatusForm a reference to the form that is actually DISPLAYED on your screen? How did you get that reference? Did you by chance declare that locally in the same place as where your thread is running so you could "have access to the form"?...

@wohlstad The objDeviceStatusForm  object is declared as I start the thread. Actually i am updating the label on Device Status Form, when i receive response from hardware device in the thread.. This error does not come every time. It is occasional.

@ArslanJaved I can only guess that it is a matter of timing: since it is a separate thread, sometimes it executes the Invoke/BeginInvoke after the window is created and sometimes only after it (and then it is OK). Maybe you can start the thread only after your GUI is fully initialized.

"The objDeviceStatusForm object is declared as I start the thread." Forms should only be created and displayed from the Main UI Thread, so hopefully you are creating it and displaying it BEFORE you hit that thread. If you want to make sure it is displayed completely before starting the work in your thread, then handle the Shown() event and signal your thread to start from there.
